# Windows not getting idle, what do to?

Tags: windows-7, windows, lock

My Windows 7 has since started to not go idle. I have a screensaver, blank screen and screen lock configuration and it is ignoring all of it. I would like to know how could I find out what is causing that and if there's any app available that would guarantee the screen gets locked after some time?

Comment: create a different profile and see if this problem continues on the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is too generic question to answer.
I would start to see what is working in background. Sometimes one hang-up process can destabilize system.

You need to experiment. Make idle delay time as small as possible, then:

Go to Task Manager and check what applications are running, check is there any occupying a lot of CPU time when You're actually not doing any heavy work, try to terminate that one and see what happens.

Anyway start with this, eventually You'll find what application is preventing computer to go to sleep.

Another option is faulty ACPI drivers, but it's hard to say now.

Comment: This is too generic to find what process is preventing standby. Just because a process uses the CPU doesn't mean it's preventing standby. Could accomplish it if there's an app which will give me the answer, but I don't know any.